# Collision Detection in iPhone SDK: Inaccurate CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: objective-c, iphone, collision-detection

When there are two objects going to collide, I check them with CGRectIntersectsRect.
However, before it returns me with YES (they collide), they are already overlapped.
Is there any other way to detect and resolve collision?

My workaround is to compare their Y axis and move the object far apart from each other, once they are detected collision.

Also, one of my objects is a circle, is there any other functions for iPhone SDK to detect the collision better? (currently I treat the circle as a rectangle, as its frame is a rectangle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some references you might try:

- [Fast Circle-Rectangle Intersection Checking](http://books.google.com/books?id=fvA7zLEFWZgC&lpg=PA51&ots=7LaInapC_l&dq=algorithm%20circle%20rectangle%20intersection&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q=algorithm%20circle%20rectangle%20intersection&f=false) from Graphic Gems (ISBN 9780122861666)
- [Circle-Rectangle collision detection (intersection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection)
- [area of intersection between circle and rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622287/area-of-intersection-between-circle-and-rectangle)

Comment: thanks for finding me references! that helps! i hope iPhone SDK will release functions for circle-rectangle collision detection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CGPath to detect collission for irregular rigid bodies. See http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/?p=379

Comment: Thanks for replying my old question. Your solution assumes the use of cocos2d engine, but at the time I ask this question, I didn't use the engine. Now, cocos2d works for me pretty well.

Comment: This site looks defunct :(