# Geometric estimation of area of cropped circle

Tags: python, area, montecarlo, geometry-surface

I have a rectangular frame and a circle with center and radius randomly generated. The center is *always* located within the limits of the frame, as shown:

[image]

I need to estimate the area of the fraction of the circle that is located within the frame. Currently I employ a simple Monte Carlo estimate that works ok, but I'd like to compare this with an exact geometric estimation of this area.

Is there a library and/or method to do this? I'm open to pretty much anything that can be installed with `conda` or `pip`.

---

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def circFrac(cx, cy, rad, x0, x1, y0, y1, N_tot=100000):
    """
    Use Monte Carlo to estimate the fraction of the area of a circle centered
    in (cx, cy) with a radius of 'rad', that is located within the frame given
    by the limits 'x0, x1, y0, y1'.
    """

    # Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50746409/1391441
    r = rad * np.sqrt(np.random.uniform(0., 1., N_tot))
    theta = np.random.uniform(0., 1., N_tot) * 2 * np.pi
    xr = cx + r * np.cos(theta)
    yr = cy + r * np.sin(theta)

    # Points within the circle that are within the frame.
    msk_xy = (xr > x0) & (xr < x1) & (yr > y0) & (yr < y1)

    # The area is the points within circle and frame over the points within
    # circle.
    return msk_xy.sum() / N_tot


for _ in range(10):

    # Random (x, y) limits of the frame
    x0, y0 = np.random.uniform(0., 500., 2)
    x1, y1 = np.random.uniform(500., 1000., 2)

    # Random center coordinates *always* within the frame
    cx = np.random.uniform(x0, x1)
    cy = np.random.uniform(y0, y1)
    # Random radius
    rad = np.random.uniform(10., 500)

    frac = circFrac(cx, cy, rad, x0, x1, y0, y1)

    plt.xlim(x0, x1)
    plt.ylim(y0, y1)
    circle = plt.Circle((cx, cy), rad, fill=False)
    plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
    plt.scatter(
        cx, cy, marker='x', c='r', label="({:.0f}, {:.0f}), r={:.0f}".format(
            cx, cy, rad))
    plt.legend()
    plt.title("Fraction of circle inside frame: {:.2f}".format(frac))
    plt.axes().set_aspect('equal')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: This might be a question better suited to the Math SE. My math-fu isn't as strong as it once was, but I have a hunch calculus would give us an exact answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it would but I was hoping for an off-the-shelf solution already implemented in some library.

Comment: +1 for posting to Math SE. I reckon it could be possible to solve geometrically by splitting the circle up into sectors and triangles, but there are a lot of different cases to account for. This is a very specific problem for a library to have a solution for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622287/area-of-intersection-between-circle-and-rectangle may give you some ideas. Despite being tagged Java, the top answer appears to be language-agnostic.

Comment: Thank you Kevin (sorry for the very late answer!) I'll check those methods and try to come up with a Python implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html) for that:

```
import shapely.geometry as g

xr,yr,r = 0,0,5
circle = g.Point(xr,yr).buffer(r)

x1,y1,x2,y2 = -1,-2,3,5
rectangle = g.Polygon([(x1,y1),(x1,y2),(x2,y2),(x2,y1)])

intersection = rectangle.intersection(circle)
intersection.area
```

[image]

Comment: This is a great library that I should use more often. Thank you Vasily!