# area of intersection of two triangles, or a set of halfplanes, or area of a convex point set

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I need to compute the area of the region of overlap between two triangles in the 2D plane. Oddly, I have written up [code](http://github.com/victorliu/Templated-Numerics/blob/master/AnalyticGeometry/TIntersection2.hpp) for the [triangle-circle problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540014/compute-the-area-of-intersection-between-a-circle-and-a-triangle), and that works quite well and robustly, but I have trouble with the triangle-triangle problem.

I already first check to see if one entirely contains the other, or if the other contains the first, as well as obtain all the edge-wise intersection points. These intersection points (up to 6, as in the star of David), combined with the triangle vertices that are contained within the other triangle, are the vertices of the intersection region. These points must form a convex polygon.

The solution I seek is the answer to either of these questions:

1. Given a set of points known to *all* lie on the convex hull of the point set, compute the area of the convex hull. Note that they are in random order.
2. Given a set of half-planes, determine the intersecting area. This is equivalent to describing both triangles as the intersection of three half-planes, and computing the solution as the direct intersection of this description.

I have considered for question 1 simply adding up all areas of all possible triangles, and then dividing by the multiplicity in counting, but that seems dumb, and I'm not sure if it is correct. I feel like there is some kind of sweep-line algorithm that would do the trick. However, the solution must also be relatively numerically robust.

I simply have no idea how to solve question 2, but a general answer would be very useful, and providing code would make my day. This would allow for direct computation of intersection areas of convex polygons instead of having to perform a triangle decomposition on them.

**Edit**: I am aware of [this article](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~plante/compGeom/index.html) which describes the general case for finding the intersection polygon of two convex polygons. It seems rather involved for just triangles, and furthermore, I don't really need the resulting polygon itself. So maybe this question is just asked in laziness at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: why are the points in a random order? If they are, you have to order them so that connecting consecutive points with straight lines yields a convex polygon. How to order them -- for example, by running a convex hull algorithm (though there are probably also simpler methods). Once you have ordered them, compute the area as described [here](http://www.mathwords.com/a/area_convex_polygon.htm).

--

Question 2 is simpler. Half-plane is defined by a single line having an implicit equation `a*x+b*y+c=0` ; all points (x, y) for which `a*x+b*y+c <= 0` (note the inequality) are "behind" the half-plane. Now, you need at least three planes so that the intersection of their negative half-spaces is closed (this is necessary, but not sufficient condition). If the intersection is closed, it will be a convex polygon.

I suggest that you maintain a linked list of vertices. The algorithm is initialized with THREE lines. Compute the three points (in general case) where the lines intersect; these are the starting vertices of your region (triangle). You must also check that each vertex is "behind" the half-plane defined by the line going through the other two vertices; this guarantees that the intersection actually IS a closed region.

These three vertices define also the the three edges of a triangle. When you intersect by a new half-plane, simply check for the intersection between the line defining the half-plane and each of the edges of the current region; in general you will get two intersection points, but you must watch out for degenerate cases where the line goes through a vertex of the region. (You can also end up with an empty set!)

The new intersection vertices define a line that splits the current region in TWO regions. Again, use orientation of the new half-plane to decide which of the two new regions to assign to the new "current region", and which one to discard.

The points in the list defining the edges of the current region will be correctly ordered so you can apply the formula in the above link to compute its area.

If this description is not detailed/understandable, the next-best advice I can give you is that you invest in a book on computational geometry and linear algebra.

Comment: Ok, in retrospect, your answer for question 2 is pretty obvious; the approach of clipping off the polygon is not as hard as I initially thought. I must be tired...