# Intersection area of polygon and circle

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

[image]

I want to calculate the Intersection area of circle and a polygon(not self intersecting). is there any good generalized algorithm.

Note: 
What I have tried: At first I try to solve the problem with Ray casting algorithm, where I will find the points in the circle and then identify the area. But it seems harder for me as the situation got harder and with complex test cases.

Input Specification :  center(x,y) and radius of the circle. vertex of the polygon( {x1,y1} , {x2,y2} , {x3,y3} ...  ).

UPDATE: The more I think I become confused. is it really possible to calculate this ?

Comment: The page you are referring to uses JavaScript. Is your question how to transform the code there to C++?

Comment: If you can cast a ray into a circle, the answer is trivial. Can you do that?

Comment: The link you give provides a solution to a different problem, the decision whether there is an intersection or not. Is that what you search actually or do you want to compute the area where circle and polygon overlap?

Comment: Thanks @UlrichEckhardt , Actually I was googling cbout the solution of Intersection area of polygon and circle" and found this page. Now I have updated the post. and again thanks to clearfy me...

Comment: Actually Ray casting algorithm, works in a different manner,  It just count odd even intersection. My final observation is this problem can not/ may not be solvable by ray casting algorithm. @BWG

Comment: I have updated the problem statement @ChristianHackl

Comment: @user3712917: Thanks for actually taking the time and removing the unnecessary tag.

Comment: @user3712917 Dude, of course i'ts solvable by raycasting. Raycasting is literally built for this purpose.

Comment: Then please answer it with your ray casting procedure. ... @BWG

Comment: @user3712917 Never mind, i didn't know what you were asking.

Comment: Any restrictions on the polygon? For example, is it always convex? Or at least not self-intersecting? At first sight, this looks like it might be pretty painful to calculate... Have to give it some thought.

Comment: the polygon is not self intersecting. Thanks for your question. It made the question more specific. I have also updated the problem statement. @RetoKoradi

Answer (score -1):

There are two steps. First, notice that this problem is easy for [triangles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/567392/6742968) - as there are no gotchas. Second, notice that you can break up any N-polygon into N triangles. This makes the situation much easier.

Any circle is described by the formula x^2 + y^2 = r^2. So you can get the area to the axis for any region of the line through integration.

I'll fill this out more tomorrow, I'm going out now.

Comment: and the alcohol made him forget to fill it out the next day :P

Comment: @FutureCake that it did.